# Parsing any file entered in command line using python

Tags: python, xml

Problem statement is to read any xml file (format of the xml file will remain same only the content will differ) entered by the user from command line which contains number of test cases, and I need to parse it, generate another xml as a output.

Currently I am using `minidom`:

```
document = parse(sys.argv[1])
```

Which can read only one specific file.

I got stuck with only this part rest all is working fine.

I need to submit it as soon as possible.

Comment: So what's the problem? Parsing the xml, parsing multiple files, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv[1]` means take the second argument, so if your command is `python foo.py abc.xml def.xml`, `argv[1]` is 'abc.xml'. You need to grab *all* the files:

```
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
   # do something for f
```